# Handle Empty Scenario Outline in Karate

Tags: karate

I have a feature file which fetches some records from DB. Now these records are then passed on to Scenario Outline examples section.

One ptoblem is there that when there are no records found then scenario outline does not gets executed which creates a problem since we do not get to know if that feature file is executed or not. I tried passing '0' into scenario outline examples section, but then it gives me an error that result is neither an list nor a function. So is there an alternate way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe you should not use a dynamic Scenario Outline. Use the `call` option, explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-features

Comment: But then over here also it will create a problem in the case when we are calling a feature file with paramter having no value. i mean results of a query will be null and while calling a feature file null will go.

Comment: @Thonas1601 read the docs carefully, you have to have a JSON array. it can't be null it has to be at least `[]` how to set up that data is up to you